# How to find the absolute path of Assets folder in android.(cross platform)

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to load an xml which is located in Assets folder using the following code

```
StreamReader strm = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("Version.xml")); 
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(strm);
```

This works fine , but i want to load through the absolute path something like this

```
var xmlFilePath = "file:///android_asset/Version.xml";
 XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
```

which is not working,suggest me a solution to find the path of Assets folder so that i can read my xml .

Comment: Unless Xamarin emulates an "absolute path" somehow, there is no such path. Assets are not files on a filesystem -- they are entries in the APK file.

Comment: thank you but i need an absolute path for the file ,so iam copying the file from Assets to my internal storage but not sure how to extract the physical file from the internal storage.

Comment: Then perhaps you should ask a separate Stack Overflow question about "how to extract the physical file from the internal storage".